# python NameError: name 'Z' is not defined but just in some executions

Tags: python

I am having this error when I instantiate this class several times. When I instantiate a few times or give it time for new instantiations this error does not occur.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\rafae\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\rafae\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\rafae\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Users\rafae\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\rafae\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\rafae\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "C:\Users\rafae\dev\patient_simulator\Controllers\PatientController.py", line 18, in hello_world
    patients.append(Patient().__dict__)
  File "C:\Users\rafae\dev\patient_simulator\Services\PatientService.py", line 36, in __init__
    self.glicose = self.gerarGlicose()
  File "C:\Users\rafae\dev\patient_simulator\Services\PatientService.py", line 109, in gerarGlicose
    y = 1/((Z**2)+0.011)*10.3
NameError: name 'Z' is not defined
```

```
class Patient:
    glicose = 0

    def __init__(self):
        self.glicose = self.gerarGlicose()

    def gerarGlicose(self):
        utils = Utils()
        if self.diabetes:
            x = utils.generateNormalNumber(87.5, 12, 10, 900)
            z = random.uniform(0.0, 1.0)
            y = 1/((Z**2)+0.011)*10.3
            return (self.volemia*(X+Y))/100
        else:
            x = utils.generateNormalNumber(87.5, 8.93, 65, 110)
            return (self.volemia * x)/100
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error occurs when your `if` statement equals `False`, which will run the `else` statement. In your `if` statement you have defined `x`, `y` and `z` but call `X`,`Y` and `Z` in your formulas. Try this.

```
class Patient:
    glicose = 0

    def __init__(self):
        self.glicose = self.gerarGlicose()

    def gerarGlicose(self):
        utils = Utils()
        if self.diabetes:
            x = utils.generateNormalNumber(87.5, 12, 10, 900)
            z = random.uniform(0.0, 1.0)
            y = 1/((z**2)+0.011)*10.3
            return (self.volemia*(x+y))/100
        else:
            x = utils.generateNormalNumber(87.5, 8.93, 65, 110)
            return (self.volemia * x)/100
```

Comment: When the statement is false i don't use the 'z' variable.

Comment: That's why it doesn't give you an error in those cases.

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning to lower case `z`, then trying to access upper case `Z`.

Same with `X` and `Y`.

Comment: I don't know why it's like this here in stackoverflow but in my code all the variables are in lower case. And how i said in the question the code just break sometimes not aways.

Comment: In your error log it’s upper case. If you really have lower case in your code, try deleting any `.pyc` files.